# AngularJS: One 'partial form' for both create and update article

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-controller

Let's take a simple form with one text input as an example. I want it to be in a partial so I can add other inputs to it and have one form for both create and update artist.

## The partial

```
<input name="name" type="text" data-ng-model="artist.name" id="name">
```

## The create form

```
<section data-ng-controller="ArtistsController">
  <form name="artistForm" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
    <ng-include src="'/modules/artists/views/partials/form-artist.client.view.html'"></ng-include>
  </form>
</section>
```

## The edit (or update) form

```
<section data-ng-controller="ArtistsController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
  <form name="artistForm" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="update(artistForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <ng-include src="'/modules/artists/views/partials/form-artist.client.view.html'"></ng-include>
  </form>
</section>
```

In my client controller, I can create an artist :

```
$scope.create = function() {
  var artist = new Artists({
    name: this.name
  });
  artist.$save(function(response) {
    //success!
  }, function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
  });
}
```

And I can update the name of an artist :

```
$scope.update = function() {
  var artist = $scope.artist;
  artist.$update(function() {
    //success!
  }, function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
  });
};
```

The issue is when I create an artist, `this.name` is undefined. If I change the data-ng-model in the parial to `data-ng-model="name"`, I can create an artist correctly but the input doesn't get filled with the name in the update form.

Any ideas on how to merge the two forms in one partial correctly?

Comment: I usually only create one form and one controller method that handle both create/update. The form really doesn't care if the object is new/existing. The controller just needs to know if it should call `$save()` or `$update()`. I determine that by checking to see if the object has an ID or not, or by setting a flag b/c I just created a new resource for the user to `save()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is actually stored in the artistForm object in the scope.

You just need to change:

```
name: this.name
```

to

```
name: $scope.artistForm.name.$viewValue
```

PS: console.log($scope) helps a lot with the investigation

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that in case of create, you have not added the artist object to a scope. U need to add the artist to a $scope.
And in the partial u should use artist.name.